# Problem formulation, definition, or statement

Tags: publications

When writing a technical report in computer science (Bachelor level), what is really the correct expression out of these:

1. Problem formulation
2. Problem definition
3. Problem statement

Do they mean exactly the same thing?

My university uses the first expression (formulation), but it doesn't feel right to me, but I am not a native english speaker.

Comment: All of them should be ok. If your university uses the first one, roll with it.

Comment: thanks @xLeitix , I will do that then. Just wanted to check because its hard as a non-native english speaker to not use direct translations sometimes.

Comment: "Problem statement" sounds best to me. To be somewhat more analytical, compare the number of results for https://scholar.google.fr/scholar?q="problem+formulation" https://scholar.google.fr/scholar?q="problem+definition" and https://scholar.google.fr/scholar?q="problem+statement" Similarly, compare results for https://google.fr/?q="problem+formulation" https://google.fr/?q="problem+definition" and https://google.fr/?q="problem+statement"

Comment: @user2768 That is a very clever method of determining what is most likely to be the "correct" term, also suitable to many other situations. Thanks!

Comment: I am computer guy and I use the third one i.e. problem statement. I do use problem formulation in case the statement needs extensive mathematical symbols or equations.